# iOS Swift: Can't create pinterest pin with PinterestSDK

Tags: ios, swift, http-status-code-404, pinterest

I am experiencing issue while trying to create pin with Pinterest SDK, I use this code:

```
PDKClient.sharedInstance().createPin(with: imageToShare, link: URL.init(string: "https://someUrl"), onBoard: "MyBoard", description: "", 
    progress: { (percent) in
    }, withSuccess: { (response) in
        print("Success")
    }) { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

And I receive this particular response:

```
Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011
"Request failed: not found (404)" UserInfo
{NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: not found (404),
NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.pinterest.com/v1/pins/
```

User is logged in into Pinterest application, just before calling this line of code, I am able to successfully create board with name MyBoard via the same API, but I am stuck within creation of the pin.
I tried to create pin with image url (because I thought that maybe it is because of my image), but it outputs the same response.
I am using twitter and facebook sdk within the same code, Info.plist seems allright.
Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the problem was, that onBoard actually requires not a board name, but it's identifier. So when you create pin board programatically -- (PDKClient.sharedInstance().createBoard) you should fetch and save it's identifier, which can be fetched in response (response.board().identifier).

I was stuck within this problem for the past 1.5 hours and figured it out just after posting the question :) I think it can be useful for someone else, because official SDK wiki is not very informative and git repository is quite dead too.

Comment: Thanks! It helped me :)